# For SPA, rewrite requests to root index.html only after checking for index.html in sub directory

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

I have an Apache site with a mix of ReactJS SPA (dynamic) routing *and* static HTML files. It's common to see rewrite strategies that direct all requests on non-existing files to `/index.html` at the root of the site.

What I need is similar, but when a request comes in to a directory, it needs to first search each directory for a (default) `index.html` file.

So if there is a request for:

```
www.example.com/this/directory/
```

It will first look for:

```
www.example.com/this/directory/index.html
```

...*before* redirecting to `www.example.com/index.html` where the React app resides.

The partial solution I have currently is:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]
```

...which *does* redirect to the root `index.html`, but *does not* first look for an `index.html` file in the subdirectory.

The static HTML portion of the site is vast, so reworking to fix all the HREFs at this point is a no-go.

I've looked around, but can't find an answer to this amongst the noise in my searching.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `RewriteCond` conditions `-f` and `-d` to check for existing files and directories, respectively:

```apache
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
# Apache will stop here if a file or directory exists.
# Add whatever you need afterwards, for example:
RewriteRule . index.html [L]
```

Comment: Is this a complete solution? I tried it just now, and it didn't work. I restarted my server too.

Comment: You can see the result at http://bbinteractive.co/_projects/marioparty/index.html by clicking a link in the main navigation.

Comment: I don't know what you need for ReactJS. Relevant for using existing files and directories are the first three lines. I edited the example to clarify this.

Comment: Well... As far as doing the basic of what React needs it's functioning the same as the solution I added in my question, but it's *not* redirecting to a sub `index.html` per my ask...

Comment: Actually, I'm seeing inconsistent results, depending on which link... It doesn't make sense though.

Comment: Yeah, there's only one link on the site that has the incorrect behavior. Now I'm trying to figure out why...

Answer (score 1):

Try something like the following:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

DirectoryIndex index.html

# Abort early if request is already for index.html in the root
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]

# Request a directory - check for index.html in that directory
# (Excludes the document root)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1/index.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1/index.html [L]

# Route all other non-file requests to index.html in the root
# (incl. directories that don't contain index.html themselves)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.html [L]
```

As per your original directives, this will route all *directories* that don't contain an `index.html` document to `index.html` in the root.

The `QSA` flag is not required here.

---

Alternatively, you could modify the `DirectoryIndex` to first check the current directory and fallback to the `/index.html` file in the root.

For example:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

# index.html in current directory, followed by /index.html (in root)
DirectoryIndex index.html /index.html

# Abort early if request is already for index.html in the root
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]

# Route all non-file/directory to index.html in the root
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.html [L]
```

This requires the additional directory check on the last rule block, otherwise all directory requests would be rewritten to `/index.html` in the root (since this would take priority).

Comment: Added alternative solution relying more on the `DirectoryIndex` directive.